# Probability Problem with arrangements

Tags: probability

There are five blocks: A, B, C, D, E arranged in order.  A cannot be first, and E cannot be last.  How many total possible permutations are there?

The book says the answer is 72 (4 * 3 * 2 * 3).

But my method yields 114 (5*4*3*2*1 - 3*2*1).  It subtracts the total number of permutations with all the permutations where A is first and E is last.  Could someone tell me why this is wrong?

Comment: What about permutations where A is first but E is not last?  Or those where A is not first but E is last?

Comment: Ugh, nevermind.  Read the question incorrectly.  Could someone delete this?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the event of $A$ being first.

Let $Y$ be the event of $E$ being last.

You want to measure: $|U\setminus(X\cup Y)|\\ = |U| - |X| - |Y| + |X\cap Y| \\ = 5! - 4!-4!+3! \\ = 78$

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of downvotes for disagreeing with both the OP and his book.

There are 5! ways of arranging the blocks.
Of these

- 4! have A in first.
- 4! have E in last.
- 3! have A in first and E in last.

Which gives 120 - 24 - 24 + 6 = 78 arrangements.

5! - 3! = 114 is wrong because, as in the comment, it ignores all the arrangements where only one of the restrictions happens.